# c# insert into database multiple times at same time with datepicker value increment

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created method `A(string date)` which inserts some data into sql table.
What's more i also have two datepickers. I want to call this method for few some period: From `dp1.Value` to `dp2.Value`. I also want to do this as quickly as possible, because there is a lot of data to insert. I've tried to do this with `Task.Run`  but result didn't satisfied me.

My A Method:

```
public void A(string date)
{
    string q1 = "SELECT val1 from table1 where cast([date] as datetime) = cast(@date as date)"
    var v1;
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q1,conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date",date)
        v1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    string q2 = "INSERT INTO table2 (v1,v2,v3,v4) VALUES (@v1,0,1,2)"
    using(SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(q2,conn))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1",v1);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

How i call this method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var od = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
        var doo = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();
        var dayDiff = DateTime.Parse(doo) - DateTime.Parse(od);
        var days = dayDiff.TotalDays;

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
        {
            A(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString());
            dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1);
            //HOW TO CALL THIS METHOD MULTIPLE TIMES AT SAME TIME FOR EACH DAY IN FOR LOOP
        }
        watch.Stop();


    }
```

Comment: If you want to insert data in bulk, use SqlBulkCopy. If you want to pass a lot of data do a query, use a table-valued type. In all cases use a *single* connection and a *single* statement.  Parallelism won't help with data loading unless you want to use multiple network cards or something.

Comment: why are you casting the date to string and back to date again everytime ? Does this not causes things to slow down ?

Comment: Indeed, casting will prevent the server from using any indexes on the `date` column, because it forces the server to process every line. It's also pointless if the parameter has is a `date` type already. Don't use `AddWithValue`, add a parameter with an explicit `date` type

Comment: How many rows are you processing at a time? You could write a simple `INSERT ... SELECT` query instead of separate SELECT and INSERT statements. If you pass the date values as a TVP, you can execute the command just once

Comment: An alternative could be to not send each insert immediate to the database, but collect them in a string and each time you have for example 100 insert commands send that to the database. This way if you have say 1000 inserts to do you will only send 10 commands to the database.

Comment: what did you try? did you get any error msg? please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @swe the OP did post what he tried and the problem is pretty obvious. This code will perform horribly, and displays some typical design problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can not even SEE a question... this IS horrible code AND horrible question

Comment: That wasn't a question... The question was, how to call A() Method multiple times at same time...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of executing separate SELECT and INSERT queries you should use a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. Since you deal with a date range, you can simply use a `BETWEEN @stardDate and @endDate` to return the rows you want from `table1`.

The double casts in the original code aren't exactly usefull, unless you stored dates as strings in the table, which is a serious bug. The only solution is to store them as proper `datetime` or `datetime` values.

Assuming `Table1.date` is a `date` value you could write a simple

```
var sql= "INSERT INTO table2 (v1,v2,v3,v4) " +
         "SELECT val1, 0, 1, 2 " +
         "FROM table1 " +
         "WHERE table1.date between @startDate and @endDate ";
```

And call the query passing the starting and ending date *values*. The DateTimePicker *already* returns the DateTime so there is no reason to cast anything or convert to string.

```
    var startDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    var endDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

If and only iff you allow the user to select a time component, you need to use `DateTime.Date` to get only the date portion. Of course, a better option is to *prevent* the user from selecting a time by setting the proper property on the controls.

The call is as simple as

```
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate",startDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate",endDate)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```